# inline width of an element determined

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out what determines the width of an "element". The picture below I cannot figure out where "inline" width comes from and it is deleting my .jQBracket? Will someone please tell me how an "inline" width gets chosen i would never come up with 943.158px; on my own.

[image]

Just found this that is probably overwriting it: is there a way to make sure its always 1100pxs?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".jQBracket").css("width", window.innerWidth - window.innerWidth / 3.8);
});
```

Comment: It's not chosen, it's probably set by the jQuery brackets plugin. If you inspect the element within the DOM you will see it has inline styles applied to it.

Comment: use `.jQBracket { width: 1100px !important }` to overwrite the inline style.

Comment: `$(".jQBracket").css("width", window.innerWidth - window.innerWidth / 7);` fixed it if anyone wants to post it as an answer

Comment: maybe window.innerWidth - (window.innerWidth/3.8) results in 943.158

Comment: it is lol and /7 = 1100 basically

Comment: _“Just found this that is probably overwriting it: is there a way to make sure its always 1100pxs?”_ – remove that script, and specify that _static_ width via your stylesheet to begin with …?

Comment: ur idea was best to remove it post it as an answer